# Logstash - How to use multiple geoip filter in one message

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, geoip

I'd like to include two geoip filter to be applied to one logstash message - let's say: A firewall message with a dst field (firewall location) and a src field (access source).

An log entry may look like this:

```
<190>2015 Mar 23 02:21:30 fw1 <50000> Dropped Inbound packet (Stateless ICMP) Src:87.245.196.38 Dst:154.54.27.169 Type:11 Code:0 IPP:1 Rule:-1 Interface:WAN (Internet)
```

The filters are defined in the logstash.conf as follows:

```
if [message] =~ "packet" {
        grok {
            match => [ 
                "message", "<%{POSINT:syslog_pri}>%{YEAR} %{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{DATA:device} <%{POSINT:status}> %{WORD:activity} %{DATA:inout} \(%{DATA:msg}\) Src:%{IPV4:src} SPort:%{INT:sport} Dst:%{IPV4:dst} DPort:%{INT:dport} IPP:%{INT:ipp} Rule:%{INT:rule} Interface:%{WORD:iface}",
                "message", "<%{POSINT:syslog_pri}>%{YEAR} %{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{DATA:device} <%{POSINT:status}> %{WORD:activity} %{DATA:inout} \(%{DATA:msg}\) Src:%{IPV4:src} Dst:%{IPV4:dst} Type:%{POSINT:type} Code:%{INT:code} IPP:%{INT:ipp} Rule:%{INT:rule} Interface:%{WORD:iface}"
            ]
        }
        geoip { source => "src" }
        geoip { source => "dst" }
}
```

The message gets parsed well (no _grokparsefailure), but only one geoip information (the last one "dst") is attached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the [geoip filter's target option](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/geoip#target) to the field where you want to store the GeoIP information for each source field.

```
filter {
    geoip {
      source => "src"
      target => "src_geoip"
    }
    geoip {
      source => "dst"
      target => "dst_geoip"
    }
}
```